# Creating list of paired elements in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I want to create a list of paired numbers. For example, I have a list of numbers as follows:

```
a = [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 30]
```

I want to create a paired list like this:

```
paired_list_a = [[1,3],[4,6],[7,9],[10,12],[13,15],[16,18],[19,20],[21,23],[24,26],[27,29]]
```

That is, I want to skip the first element and pair the numbers with the one next to them with minus one.

I tried something like this but no luck

```
paired_list_a = [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 21, 24, 27, 30]
row = [[a[i],a[i+1]-1] for i in range(len(a))]
```

but it is throwing `IndexError: list index out of range`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is list `b` for?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can get by `zip`, For more info https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/

Comment: You need to use `range(len(a)-1)`, otherwise `a[i+1]` is outside the list.

Comment: Just use zip: `[[n, m-1] for n, m in zip(a, a[1:])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the last number doesn't has a successor. You should try something like:

```
row = [[a[i],a[i+1]-1] for i in range(len(a)-1)]
```

If you have a pattern in the numbers (for example: every item is last_item + 2) you could pair the last value without the cycle.

```
row[-1] = [a[-1], a[-1]+2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip` here with all values of same list without first value:

```
row = [[x, y - 1] for x, y in zip(a, a[1:])]
print (row)

[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9], [10, 12], [13, 15], [16, 18], [19, 20], [21, 23], [24, 26], [27, 29]]
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly working. Thank you so much! Can you update your code so that I can get the following output?  `[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9], [10, 12], [13, 15], [16, 18], [19, 20], [21, 23], [24, 26], [27, 30]]`` I want the last element of lists to be inclusive, which means I want the last elements to contain `[27,30]`.

Comment: But possible by `row = [[x, y - 1] if len(a) != i else [x, y] for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, a[1:]), 2)]
`

Comment: @user86907 - Advice - in future is best ask in next question ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is out of range because for the last iteration of the loop, you access the a+1 index.

```
# change range(len(a)) to range(len(a)-1)
row = [[a[i],a[i+1]-1] for i in range(len(a)-1)]

[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9], [10, 12], [13, 15], [16, 18], [19, 20], [21, 23], [24, 26], [27, 29]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = [] 
for index, item in enumerate(a[:-2]):
    res.append([item, a[index+1]-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use :

`range(len(a)-1)` instead of `range(len(a))` which is the main reason you are getting `IndexError: list index out of range` error